# Winforms, Minimized, Text

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to WinForms and am currently developing a simple application. I am not too sure if it is possible, but I would like to display the Form's text value (or some text value) in the taskbar when the application is minimized, rather than the icon?

Comment: You could try setting the Form.Text property. But it depends as well on the OS you are using. As Win7 is having icons only in the taskbar, while Win Xp did have some text in the taskbar.

Comment: @FlorisPrijt Win7 _does_ have text in the taskbar when a Form is minimized. Perhaps you mean a program that's not running ("Quick launch").

Comment: @ispiro Win7 doesn't, unless you [set it](http://lifehacker.com/5130368/add-text-to-the-windows-7-taskbar-buttons)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I would like the text to appear in the taskbar, that is the bar in Win7 where you launch your applications. When you minimize your application the applications icon appears. What I would like to do, if possible, is to display the form text value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Rohit Vyas's. But due to your comment, you're looking for:

> Right-click on taskbar -> Properties -> Taskbar buttons: Never
>   Combine.

Comment: Just a follow on question. If I didn't have the taskbar setting to be "Never Combine". Is there a way to programically display the text rather than an icon? For example, when the user minimizes the application the time appears on the taskbar and is updated i.e. ticking?

Comment: @RT88 Not that I know of. But you can look into Killercam's answer - Perhaps a system tray icon can show text. Or ask another question here on Stack Overflow. Maybe someone else will know.

Comment: @RT88 By the way - "Combine when taskbar is full" can also be used. Not only "Never Combine".

Comment: Thanks! It just that I remember that some applications in the past displayed (and dynamically) updated the form's text value (and in some cases displayed a minimized version of the application in the taskbar as well?) when the application was minimized.

Comment: @RT88 The "minimized version" is automatic. Hover on the taskbar icon to see it. If you mean that the icon itself was like that - perhaps that's possible in the notification area.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the text of your application by:

```
 this.Text = "Text that you want to display";
```

paste the above line of code in your Form's constructor just below the `InitializeComponent()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without going into COM/Interop stuff and even then I would not advise it. Why not use a text icon instead, or you could look at the [NotfyIcon Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9szb3e6y.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Title usually appears in the taskbar of Win xp and many windows 
it can be set like this in win forms

```
This.Text ="Some Text";
```

But in Win 7 it will always give you the icon unless you change the properties of windows.